# How to average with MongoDB taking 10 chunks and so on in Python?

Tags: python, database, mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregation

I want to average of 10000 records but every 10 values(10 chunks out of 10000 chunks) I want to average and store that 10 values average and then move to next 10 in the value in documents in MongoDb,

```
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "abc", "price" : 10, "quantity" : 2, "date" : ISODate("2014-03-01T08:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : 2, "item" : "jkl", "price" : 20, "quantity" : 1, "date" : ISODate("2014-03-01T09:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : 3, "item" : "xyz", "price" : 5, "quantity" : 10, "date" : ISODate("2014-03-15T09:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : 4, "item" : "xyz", "price" : 5, "quantity" : 20, "date" : ISODate("2014-04-04T11:21:39.736Z") }
{ "_id" : 5, "item" : "abc", "price" : 10, "quantity" : 10, "date" : ISODate("2014-04-04T21:23:13.331Z") }
```

In following documents I want to take average of price every 2 documents like 10+20/2 = 15 and 5+5/2= 5. So I like to know how to make this in Python.

Comment: what's the expected output? array of averages?

Comment: average of every 10 values

Comment: This documents have only 5 values so I given example as taking two values as average I hope you understand

Comment: I want to calculate moving average but every 10 values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this aggregation pipeline to partition the prices and calculate average for each partition,

replace all 2 to 10, to partition by 10

```
db.avgs.aggregate([
    {$sort : {_id : 1}},
    {$group : {_id : null, prices : {$push : "$price"}}},
    {$project : { _id : 0, average : {
        $map : {
            input : {$range : [0, {$ceil : {$divide : [{$size : "$prices"},2]}}]},
            as : "r",
            in : {$avg : {$slice : ["$prices", {$multiply : ["$$r", 2]}, 2]}}
        }
    }}}
]).pretty()
```

result

```
{ "average" : [ 15, 5, 10 ] }
```

Comment: I think this works, can I know when i convert the script to python one line showing me error as : "r",
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Try enclosing with double quotes

Comment: in : {"$avg" : {"$slice" :  the in and as is making me issues I used double quotes but the issue persist in python can you guide little in this.